# Python: No csv.close()?

Tags: python, csv

I'm using the CSV module to read a tab delimited file. Code below:

```
z = csv.reader(open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/output.blast'), delimiter='\t')
```

But when I add Z.close() to end of my script i get and error stating "csv.reader' object has no attribute 'close'"

```
z.close()
```

So how do i close "Z"?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The reader is really just a parser. When you ask it for a line of data, it delegates the reading action to the underlying `file` object and just converts the result into a set of fields. The reader itself doesn't manage any resources that would need to be cleaned up when you're done using it, so there's no need to close it; it'd be a meaningless operation.

You should make sure to close the underlying `file` object, though, because that *does* manage a resource (an open file descriptor) that needs to be cleaned up. Here's the way to do that:

```
with open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/output.blast') as f:
    z = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    # do whatever you need to with z
```

If you're not familiar with the [`with` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), it's roughly equivalent to enclosing its contents in a `try...finally` block that closes the file in the `finally` part.

Hopefully this doesn't matter (and if it does, you really need to update to a newer version of Python), but the `with` statement was introduced in Python 2.5, and in that version you would have needed a `__future__` import to enable it. If you were working with an even older version of Python, you would have had to do the closing yourself using `try...finally`.

---

<sup>Thanks to [Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290784) for pointing out compatibility issues with the `with` statement.</sup>

Answer (score 40):

You do not close CSV readers directly; instead you should close whatever file-like object is being used.  For example, in your case, you'd say:

```
f = open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/output.blast')
z = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
...
f.close()
```

If you are using a recent version of Python, you can use the with statement, e.g.

```
with open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/output.blast') as f:
    z = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    ...
```

This has the advantage that `f` will be closed even if you throw an exception or otherwise return inside the with-block, whereas such a case would lead to the file remaining open in the previous example.  In other words, it's basically equivalent to a try/finally block, e.g.

```
f = open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/output.blast')
try:
    z = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    ...
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't close the result of the `reader()` method, you close the result of the `open()` method. So, use two statements: `foo=open(...); bar=csv.reader(foo)`. Then you can call `foo.close()`.

There are no bonus points awarded for doing in one line that which can be more readable and functional in two.