# Removing Duplicate CSV Entries with python

Tags: python, csv

I have just completed a script that (sigh) finally works.  It searches twitter for keywords.  The results are written to a csv with 4 columns of keyword, Tweet, Lat, Lon (location). The code that I'm using is:

```
import tweepy
import csv

keywordList = ['McDonalds', 'Taco Bell', 'Burger King',]
for keyword in keywordList:
    result = tweepy.api.search(q=keyword,rpp=1000,page=2, geocode= "34.085422,-117.900879,500mi" )

    with open(r'C:\Temp\results.csv', 'a') as acsv:
        w = csv.writer(acsv)
        for tweet in result:
            lat, lon = tweet.geo if tweet.geo else ('', '')
            try:
                a = tweet.geo['coordinates']
                print a[0] , a[1]
                print tweet.text
                w.writerow((keyword, tweet.text, a[0] , a[1]))
            except:
                pass
```

I want to use task manager or python to run this search every 5 minutes but It will rewrite duplicates.  I was going to use the following code to remove duplicates but two things happen.  The resutls2.csv is blank and when I go to open the csv, it is locked and I have to view it in a read only.  I tried f1.close(), writer.close() etc but it says 'csv.reader' object has no attribute close.

My biggest concern is getting no duplicates either by writing to the new csv or somehow removing and writing to the same table on each search.  Any suggestions are much appreciated!!

```
import csv

f1 = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Temp\results.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open(r'C:\Temp\results2.csv', 'wb'))
tweet = set()
for row in f1:
    if row[1] not in tweet:
        writer.writerow(row)
        tweet.add( row[1] )
f1.close()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Use a database and declare a unique constraint over the combination of columns that you want to be different... If you don't want to run a database, just use sqlite.

Comment: Perhaps a more general advice than Endophage did: Why don't you extend your script to read the previously generated `.csv` file and add entries only if they don't exist?

Comment: @user946850 Thats what I'd like to do.  I did this script above to test to see if it works first.  Then I was going to add it into the original script.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216954/python-no-csv-close deals with closing CSV readers and writers. Your code looks right except that you allow only one tweet per keyword. Not sure if this matches your requirements.

Comment: @user946850 No it returns multiple tweets per keyword but only returns when there is geolocation.  Not sure why Im getting a blank csv when I run the new code

Comment: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10905273/edit) instead of posting the code in a comment

Comment: See the `with` keyword and its usage in the Python docs. (You have actually used it already in the first script.) Learning by example is good, but try to avoid [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: yes. You could try to use `since_id` or `max_id` to avoid downloading the same tweets in the first place or/and use streaming api to avoid running the script every 5 minutes. Also click the link provided by @user946850

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactored version:

**Edit:** unicode, what fun - I've added a .decode() call in read_csv() and an .encode() call in append_csv(); this should solve your problem (I think - you might need to decide on a string codec).

```
import tweepy
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import time

FILE = 'c:/temp/results.csv'
KEYWORDS = ['McDonalds', 'Taco Bell', 'Burger King']
WHERE = "34.085422,-117.900879,500mi"
DELAY = 300  # seconds

def _float(s, err=None):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return err

def _str(f, err=""):
    return err if f is None else str(f)

def read_csv(fname=FILE):
    data = defaultdict(dict)
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        for kw,tw,lat,lon in incsv:
            # added .decode() call to handle saved unicode chars
            data[kw][tw.decode()] = (_float(lat), _float(lon))
    return data

def append_csv(data, fname=FILE):
    with open(fname, "ab") as outf:
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
        # added .encode() call to handle saved unicode chars
        outcsv.writerows((kw,tw.encode(),_str(lat),_str(lon)) for kw,dat in data.iteritems() for tw,(lat,lon) in dat.iteritems())

def search_twitter(keywords=KEYWORDS, loc=WHERE):
    data = defaultdict(dict)
    for kw in keywords:
        for tweet in tweepy.api.search(q=kw, rpp=1000, page=2, geocode=loc):
            data[kw][tweet.text] = tweet.geo if tweet.geo else (None,None)
    return data

def calc_update(old_data, new_data):
    diff = defaultdict(dict)
    for kw,dat in new_data.iteritems():
        for tw,loc in dat.iteritems():
            if tw not in old_data[kw]:
                diff[kw][tw] = old_data[kw][tw] = loc
    return old_data, diff

def show_data(data):
    for kw,dat in data.iteritems():
        for tw,(lat,lon) in dat.iteritems():
            print("<{},{}> {} [{}]".format(_str(lat,"???"), _str(lon,"???"), tw, kw))

def main():
    data = read_csv()
    while True:
        new_data  = search_twitter()
        data,diff = calc_update(data, new_data)
        append_csv(diff)
        show_data(diff)
        time.sleep(DELAY)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @ Hugh Bothwell  Thank you for that.  I wasn't expecting someone to rewrite the entire code.  While that is appreciated, I am getting this error: `line 31, in append_csv
    outcsv.writerows((kw,tw,_str(lat),_str(lon)) for kw,dat in data.iteritems() for tw,(lat,lon) in dat.iteritems())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @ Hugh Bothwell I still get the same error.  Below, I copied and pasted my excel sheet.  The top part is what is produced when I run my original code.  It only returns tweets with geo locations (which I want).  The bottom part is yours.  I think the unicode error is with the lat long.  `Burger King, You don't want no dry biscuit lol to funny@burger king,31.5553,-110.358
   

McDonalds, Is may be just me but watchin Super Size Me always makes me want some Mcdonalds!`  
 The results typically look like this: @Jessica Mcdonalds is good {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [33.9443, -118.0038]}