# Closing DictReader necessary or possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
filenames = glob('directory*.csv')   

for filename in filenames:
   f = csv.DictReader(open(filename))
   #code

f.close()
```

Hello. I'm not entirely familiar with `DictReader`.

Does this need to be closed after use? i.e. `f.close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following question is a duplicate of [Python No CSV Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216954/python-no-csv-close). 
That said, from my understanding since DictReader is a parser on the CSV, there is no need to close it. However, the underlying file should get closed when finished.

Comment: None of the comments on that page seem to work for me.

Comment: Nevermind. Got it

Comment: @Anonypy: Every answer there says the same thing. You're supposed to close the file object returned by `open`, not the `csv` parsing wrapper object. Don't inline the `open` inside the `DictReader`, call `open` using a `with` statement (so it autocloses when the block completes) and you don't need (and shouldn't) do anything to close `DictReader` itself.